# How to get the status of a build on GithHub through PyGitHub

Tags: python, github, github-actions, github-api, pygithub

I have a text file with a list of repos. I wanted to use pygithub to iterate through the list and tell me for each repo on whether the last build was successful or failure on dev or master branch depending on which one exists. This is what I have

```
from github import Github

g = Github(base_url="https://code.secret.url/api/v3", login_or_token="SECRET_TOKEN")
user = g.get_user()
login = user.login

org = g.get_organization("SECRET_ORG")


# Open the file containing the list of repositories
with open("repo_list.txt") as f:
    for repo_name in f:
        
        repo = org.get_repo(repo_name.strip())
        try:
            print(f"Processing repo: {repo_name.strip()}")

            # Get branches as a PaginatedList object
            branches = repo.get_branches()

            # Check if the 'dev' branch exists
            dev_branch_exists = False
            for branch in branches:
                if branch.name == 'dev':
                    dev_branch_exists = True
                    break

            # Set base_branch to either dev or master
            if dev_branch_exists:
                base_branch = repo.get_branch("dev")
            else:
                base_branch = repo.get_branch("master")

            # Get the latest commit
            latest_commit = base_branch.commit
            print(f"Latest commit: {latest_commit}")

            # Check the status of the latest commit
            statuses = latest_commit.get_statuses()
            print(f"Statuses: {statuses}")
            
            # Print the statuses if available
            if statuses:
                print("List of statuses:")
                for status in statuses:
                    print(f"State: {status.state}, Description: {status.description}")
            else:
                print("No statuses found for the latest commit.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while processing {repo_name.strip()}: {str(e)}")
```

When I try printing the status it appears to be empty because in the log it will say

```
List of statuses:
```

but nothing prints afterwards meaning it doesn't even execute `print(f"State: {status.state}, Description: {status.description}")`. I used the following documentation as reference https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Commit.html#github.Commit.Commit.get_statuses

It's easy for me to see the status of a repo just by using the UI of github and just clicking on action of a repo but I was hoping to do this through automation. When I try printing out status from

```
 # Check the status of the latest commit
 statuses = latest_commit.get_statuses()
 print(f"Statuses: {statuses}")
```

It will print out something like `<github.PaginatedList.PaginatedList object at 0x000001CD1AF03310>`
so I am certain that I am populating the variable statues correctly with .get_statuses() but afterwards I am not certain if what I am doing is the correct way. I forgot to mention print(f"Latest commit: {latest_commit}") also appears to print correctly so I don't think there's an issue with the commit I'm grabbing

UPDATE: I also tried the following code snippet as per someone's suggestion

```
# Get the last commit associated with the pull request
  last_commit = pr.get_commits().reversed[0].commit
  print(f"Last commit SHA: {last_commit.sha}")

  # Get the check runs associated with the last commit
  check_runs = last_commit.get_check_runs()

  # Check if all check runs have a conclusion of "success"
  passing = all(check.conclusion == "success" for check in check_runs)
  print("Build passed? ", passing)
```

But it gave me the error `'GitCommit' object has no attribute 'get_check_runs'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that commit status is something different to GH Action result.

From [GitHub Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/collaborating-on-repositories-with-code-quality-features/about-status-checks#types-of-status-checks-on-github)

> There are two types of status checks on GitHub:
>
> - Checks
> - Statuses
>
> Checks are different from statuses in that they
> provide line annotations, more detailed messaging, and are only
> available for use with GitHub Apps.

Based on this, I think statuses might be the correct one for CI-systems other than GH Actions, but for GH Actions you need to query for checks.

If you want to check whether all the checks for the latest commit were successful, this works:

```
check_runs = latest_commit.get_check_runs()
passing = all([check.conclusion == "success" for check in check_runs])
print("Build passed? ", passing)
```

`get_check_runs()` lists results for all the checks executed for the commit, and you can iterate over them to for example note if `conclusion` for all of them was `"success"`.

Comment: I tried this but got the error: 'GitCommit' object has no attribute 'get_check_runs'
I updated my post with code that I incorporated from your post

Comment: This works for me for the original example you provided. Commit definitely has that function https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/cd8e528d8f0f4eeed087845b57f7d1b671739bb4/github/Commit.py#L233, but GitCommit (https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/main/github/GitCommit.py) does not. `pr.get_commits().reversed[0].commit` is the inner type, but `pr.get_commits().reversed[0].get_check_runs()`  should work.

Comment: Ok listen. PaginatedList (https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/main/github/PaginatedList.py) is the type of the list containing the commits. It's what you get with pr.get_commits(). Now you are trying to call the function for that list, which obviously does not work. You need to access one of the actual commits inside that list. 

Please share the line of code where you get that error. Is it something like `pr.get_commits().reversed.get_check_runs()` instead of `pr.get_commits().reversed[0].get_check_runs()`?

Comment: Sorry I had accidently forgot to include reversed[0]. Now it prints out the value though its not correct. It says the build passed? False even though my PR has a green build and one build that was skipped. I tried changing success to Successful  but that didn't help either

Comment: Oh its because I used all instead of any. After changing it works. Will try to figure out how to get it to a specific build

Comment: Got that working as well. I just needed to slightly modify the code to include check.name == action_name. Thanks for your help